# ASP.NET Identity получить всех пользователей

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые форумчане.
Использую авторизацию ASP.NET Identity и возник вопрос как в обычном контроллере получить список всех пользователей куда и как лезть.попутно еще использую при этом ninject.
Вот код контроллера

```
private IPhotoRepository repository;
private UserManager<ApplicationUserView> UserManager;
public HomeController(IPhotoRepository repository)
{
    this.repository = repository;
    UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUserView>(new UserStore<ApplicationUserView>(this.repository.ApplicationUsers)); ;
}
```

Реализация интерфейса IPhotoRepository

```
private PhotoDbContext _context = new PhotoDbContext();

public DbContext ApplicationUsers
{
    get { return _context; }
}
```

реализация DBContext

```
public class PhotoDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public PhotoDbContext() : base("Proba")
    {
    }    
}
```

Заранее спасибо:)